# The essential norm where some Fourier coefficients are fixed

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Let us denote $C_{2\pi}$ by the set of all $2\pi$-periodic continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$.

Q. Let $\phi\in C_{2\pi}$. Is the following statement valid?
$$\|\phi\|_2=\inf_{g\in C_{2\pi}}\Big\{\|\phi+g\|_{\infty} : \phi*g=0 \Big\}$$

p.s. $\|f\|_{\infty}$ is just the maximum of the absolute value of $f$ and $\phi*g$ means the convolution product of $\phi$ and $g$.

Comment: If $\hat{\phi}(k)=0$ whenever $|k|>n$ whereas $\hat{g}(k)=0$ whenever $|k| \le n$, then $\phi$ and $g$ are orthogonal so $$||\phi+g||_\infty^2 \ge  ||\phi+g||_2^2 =  ||\phi||_2^2 + ||g||_2^2 \ge  ||\phi||_2^2.$$

Comment: Nice and thanks.

Comment: So it seems the infimum is  the $L^2$-norm of $\phi$ !

Comment: No, since the $L^\infty$ norm is greater than the $L^2$ norm.

Comment: Based on the comments, the problem has been edited.